# Java Array Manipulation

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function named resize, which takes a source array, and resizes to new widths and height. The method I'm using, I think, is inefficient. I heard there's a better way to do it. Anyway, the code below works when scale is an int. However, there's a second function called half, where it uses resize to shrink an image in half. So I made scale a double, and used a typecast to convert it back to an int. This method is not working, and I dont know what the error is (the teacher uses his own grading and tests on these functions, and its not passing it). Can you spot the error, or is there a more efficient way to make a resize function?

```
public static int[][] resize(int[][] source, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

        int[][] newImage=new int[newWidth][newHeight];
        double scale=newWidth/(source.length);
        for(int i=0;i<newWidth/scale;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<newHeight/scale;j++)
                for (int s1=0;s1<scale;s1++) 
                    for (int s2=0;s2<scale;s2++) 
                        newImage[(int)(i*scale+s1)][(int)(j*scale+s2)] =source[i][j];

        return newImage; 
    }

    /**
     * Half the size of the image. This method should be just one line! Just
     * delegate the work to resize()!
     */
    public static int[][] half(int[][] source) {
        int[][] newImage=new int[source.length/2][source[0].length/2];
        newImage=resize(source,source.length/2,source[0].length/2);
        return newImage;
    }
```

Comment: I know I've see basically the same question asked here already.

Comment: Probably from the same guy!  Heyas, fprime!

Comment: do you need to do a general resize or just to scale the image by 0.5?

Comment: I need a general resize, but should work for half scaling as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one scheme for changing the size of an image is to resample it (technically this is really the only way, every variation is really just a different kind of resampling function).

Cutting an image in half is super easy, you want to read every other pixel in each direction, and then load that pixel into the new half sized array.  The hard part is making sure your bookkeeping is strong.

```
static int[][] halfImage(int[][] orig){
    int[][] hi = new int[orig.length/2][orig[0].length/2];

    for(int r = 0, newr = 0; r < orig.length; r += 2, newr++){
        for(int c = 0, newc = 0; c < orig[0].length; c += 2, newc++){
            hi[newr][newc] = orig[r][c];
        }
    }

    return hi;
}
```

In the code above I'm indexing into the original image reading every other pixel in every other row starting at the 0th row and 0th column (assuming images are row major, here).  Thus, `r` tells us which row in the original image we're looking at, and `c` tells us which column in the original image we're looking at.  `orig[r][c]` gives us the "current" pixel.

Similarly, `newr` and `newc` index into the "half-image" matrix designated `hi`.  For each increment in `newr` or `newc` we increment `r` and `c` by 2, respectively.  By doing this, we skip every other pixel as we iterate through the image.

Writing a generalized resize routine that doesn't operate on nice fractional quantities (like 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc.) is really pretty hard.  You'd need to define a way to determine the value of a sub-pixel -- a point between pixels -- for more complicated factors, like 0.13243, for example.  This is, of course, easy to do, and you can develop a very naive linear interpolation principle, where when you need the value between two pixels you simply take the surrounding pixels, construct a line between their values, then read the sub-pixel point from the line.  More complicated versions of interpolation might be a `sinc` based interpolation...or one of many others in widely published literature.

Blowing up the size of the image involves something a little different than we've done here (and if you do in fact have to write a generalized resize function you might consider splitting your function to handle upscaling and downscaling differently).  You need to somehow create more values than you have originally -- those interpolation functions work for that too.  A trivial method might simply be to repeat a value between points until you have enough, and slight variations on this as well, where you might take so many values from the left and so many from the right for a particular position.

What I'd encourage you to think about -- and since this is homework I'll stay away from the implementation -- is treating the scaling factor as something that causes you to make observations on one image, and writes on the new image.  When the scaling factor is less than 1 you generally sample from the original image to populate the new image and ignore some of the original image's pixels.  When the scaling factor is greater than 1, you generally write more often to the new image and might need to read the same value several times from the old image.  (I'm doing a poor job highlighting the difference here, hopefully you see the dualism I'm getting at.)

Comment: Thanks for the informative post. The problem is my original resize method is done wrong to begin with. The teacher says: "Hints: Use two nested for loops between 0... newWidth-1 and 0.. newHeight-1 inclusive." So I did my own version cuz that method wasnt working for me. But Im sure there is a way to do it where I dont treat scale factors less than 1 different from larger than 1. The problem Im having with this code is just the double to int typecasting is giving problems for when the scale is not an int. This is what needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty understandable, and I think it **IS** an O(n^4) algorithm.  Ouchies!

You can improve it slightly by pushing the `i*scale` and `j*scale` out of the inner two loops - they are invariant where they are now.  The optimizer might be doing it for you, however.  There are also some other similar optimizations.

Regarding the error, run it twice, once with an input array that's got an even length (6x6) and another that's odd (7x7).  And 6x7 and 7x6 while you're at it.

Comment: The teacher says "Hints: Use two nested for loops between 0... newWidth-1 and 0.. newHeight-1 inclusive." I tried that method, but that didnt work out too well for me. And I really didnt understand your answer above. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your other question, it seems like you may be having trouble with mixing of types - with numeric conversions.  One way to do this, which can make your code more debuggable and more readable to others not familiar with the problem space, would be to split the problematic line into multiple lines.  Each minor operation would be one line, until you reach the final value.  For example,

```
newImage[(int)(i*scale+s1)][(int)(j*scale+s2)] =source[i][j];
```

would become

```
int x = i * scale;
x += s1;
int y = j* scale;
y +=s2;

newImage[x][y] = source[i][j];
```

Now, you can run the code in a debugger and look at the values of each item after each operation is performed.   When a value doesn't match what you think it should be, look at it and figure out why.

Now, back to the suspected problem:  I expect that you need to use doubles somewhere, not ints - in your other question you talked about scaling factors.   Is the factor less than 1?  If so, when it's converted to an int, it'll be 0, and you'll get the wrong result.

Comment: Well I get a divide by zero error, so I know what the value scale is holding. I read somewhere that I can resize by just making a new array with the desired dimensions and copying the contents using array.copy (or whatever it is for Java). What would be the problem with this approach, if any?

Comment: The only issue I can think of with resizing like that, off the top of my head, is that this could become operationally intensive if you do it for very large arrays or a large number of times.  Each time you copy the array, each value in the array must be written to the new array.  Do this enough and you use a lot of CPU.  Do this with large enough arrays and you use a lot of RAM.  You may want to consider using a subclass of java.util.List to handle the resize more cleanly.

Comment: How could I do this resize using the arraycopy method?

Comment: If you use a class that automatically resizes for you, you don't have to do anyhing special-  you just add data to the object and, if you add too much, the object grows bigger..  On the other hand, your implementaition looks may depend on the size of the array for more than just storage space.  If so, you'd need to refactor to just store and retrieve data without worrying so much about size.