# Java- Identifying ints and doubles

Tags: java, types

I want to write a conditional statement, depending on whether a variable is an int or double, i.e

```
if (x is a double)
  do stuff
else if(x is an int)
  do stuff
else
  do stuff
```

I know this might not be a good idea, but its my only choice for now. Is this possible?

Comment: You know at compile time what type a primitive variable is in Java.  Under what circumstances do you need to check with a conditional statement?  Are you converting user input from a String or something?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out a case for this. Is there more to this question?

Comment: Well its for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886818/java-array-manipulation  I'm just having problems when the int scale factor is 0.5. So I was thinking if I have different instructions depending on if its a double or not, I might eliminate the problem. Its a last hope type of thing. I dont know what else to do.

Comment: *How do I know if I'm Jewish? / Are you Jewish? / No. / There you go, sport. / Thank you!*

Comment: like I imply in my answer to your other question: ints are integers.  They are the numbers in the set (...-1, 0, 1...).  This does not include decimals.  If you need to use a decimal, you need to use a float or a double.  When you use a scale of int scale=0.5, you really have int scale=0 - integers truncate decimals.  If you're using an integer and a double or float, you need to be aware of aritmatic conversions.  I believe that floats are converted to ints when multiplied by ints, but I'm not wholly sure - quick testing or a look at the documentation would tell you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea how x could be an int or a double without you knowing at compile time, but

```
void dostuff(int x) {
    do stuff...
}

void dostuff(double x) {
    do stuff...
}
```

then

```
dostuff(x)
```

will call the appropriate method.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to add:***I don't think this question is really what you want, based on your comment to the original question.  I'll post a comment on the other question to try and offer some assistance to yoru real issue.*

As Bill the Lizard says, you'll know at compile time what type a primitive is:

```
public void foo(int x, double y){...}
```

On the other hand, if you're putting your types inside another object, like

```
Vector v = new Vector();
v.add((int)1);
v.add((double)1.0));
```

then you're really dealing with objects not primitives.  Each primitive has a corresponding class:

- int has Integer
- double has Double
- float has Float
- boolean has Boolean
- etc.

You can use the instanceof keyword to determine what type you're dealing with (you can do this with any class):

```
if( x instanceof Double ) {
  doDoubleThing();
} else if( x instanceof Integer ) {
  doIntegerThing();
} // and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to check if a number has a decimal part or not.

```
double n;
if(n-floor(n)>0)
    it has a decimal part
else
    it's an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

What atk wrote is valid if you have the ability to use two methods. If this isn't an option or you don't want to do this (personally think it might be more readable and less repetitious to have one method and just do an if-else branch, depends on your code), you can use reflection:

```
Class intClass = Integer.class;
Class doubleClass = Double.class;
if intClass.isInstance(foo)
    bar();
else if doubleClass.isInstance(foo)
    spam();
else
    eggs();
```

This might not necessarily be the best solution. Just thought you should know about it.